Invertibility of tridiagonal operators
Are there any criteria or sufficient condition for the invertibility of tridiagonal operators in $l^2 (\mathbb{Z})$ ? This question arose from the following task — I needed to find the conditions for the invertibility of Gram's matrix for some basis vectors of some subspace in $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$.
I was advised to consider symmetrical tridiagonal operators and then to study the perturbation theory, but I had no success in finding forementioned criteria for the symmetrical tridiagonal operators as well. One of the articles gave a hint to look for the LDU-decomposition of an operator, but again it didn't lead me to an answer to my question.
Can anyone help me to find the solution to this problem?
